# Chronological ordering with the $week operator

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The $week operator works great when you're grouping documents by dates within a week. However, is there a sort operator that can sort the document chronologically rather than numerically?

I'd like to sort documents in such a way that it is easy to see grouping as they cross over the new year. My understanding is that the options are either 0-53 or 53-0.

When I run the aggregation on January 10th, I'd like documents ordered 1, 0, 53, 52, 51...

Is this possible?

```
db.users.aggregate([
{$match : {dateC : {$gte : new ISODate('2014-12-01')}}},
{$project : {now : {$week:new Date()},dateC:1}},
{$group : { _id:{ week : {"$week":"$dateC"}, now : "$now"}, 
            count : {$sum:1} } },
{ $sort : {'_id.week':1} }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding the year to the aggregation:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$match : {dateC : {$gte : new ISODate('2014-12-01')}}},
    {$project : {
        week: {$week:"$dateC"},
        year: {$year:"$dateC"},
    }},
    {$group : {
        _id:{ year : "$year", week : "$week"},
        count : {$sum : 1}
    }},
    {$sort : {'_id.year':-1, "_id.week" : -1}}
]);
```

Be careful though, weeks without any data won't show on the results.